# PhantomJS - Get the element rendered completely regardless of the window scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs

A page is loaded and one particular div element is converted into an image.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = { width: 1440, height: 900 };
page.open(jsonContent["imageURL"], function() {


  var clipRect = page.evaluate(function(){
    return document.getElementsByClassName('permalink-content-container').item(0).getBoundingClientRect();
  });

  if (clipRect != null) {
   page.clipRect = {
    top:    clipRect.top,
    left:   clipRect.left,
    width:  clipRect.width,
    height: clipRect.height
  };

  atob(page.renderBase64('png'))
  page.close()
});
```

If the div element `permalink-content-container` is taller than the screen, a part of it is hidden below the view port (needs to be scrolled) and is not rendered as the final image. Is there a way I can render the complete div element regardless of the viewport height?

Comment: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/zoom-factor.html

Comment: @Rayon adding a zoomfactor renders the background  content of the page that is behind the div container element.